# Unexpected array to string conversion

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, casting

I'm trying to pack my data into objects before displaying them with `ConvertTo-Json`. The test case below shows perfectly how I'm dealing with data and what problem occurs:

```
$array = @("a","b","c")
$data = @{"sub" = @{"sub-sub" = $array}}
$output = @{"root" = $data}
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $output
```

Output (formatted by hand for clarity):

```
          { "sub": { "sub-sub": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }}
{ "root": { "sub": { "sub-sub": "a b c" } }}
```

Is there any way to assign `$data` to `$output` without this weird implicit casting?

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $output -Depth 3`

Comment: Thank you!
...although -Depth 1 gives System.Collections.Hashtable for "sub-sub"
but -Depth 2 gives "a b c" for ["a","b","c"] instead of Object[] 
and I think this is very illogical

Comment: `Depth` is simply the number of nested levels at which PowerShell will "unravel" a value. Otherwise, it'll default to the objects string representation, which is exactly what yo see

Comment: And by string representation you mean "[string]" and not "... | Out-String". Now it's clear.

Comment: Correct, the object itself is cast to a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `ConvertTo-Json` will try to *flatten* the object structure beyond a maximum nesting level, or *depth*, by converting whatever object it finds beyond that depth to a string.

The default depth is 2, but you can specify that it should go deeper with the `Depth` parameter:

```
PS C:\> @{root=@{level1=@{level2=@("level3-1","level3-2")}}}|ConvertTo-Json
{
    "root":  {
        "level1":  {
            "level2":  "level3-1 level3-2"
        }
    }
}
PS C:\> @{root=@{level1=@{level2=@("level3-1","level3-2")}}}|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
{
    "root":  {
        "level1":  {
            "level2":  [
                "level3-1",
                "level3-2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```